# Write a function that adds all the numbers passed as arguments without using a loop

Tags: javascript

```
add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // => 15
```

Is there any way of doing this without using a while or a for loop.

Comment: Why not use a loop? You could do it recursively, but that would consume more resources than a simple loop would.

Comment: Actually I saw this question somewhere and couldn't find a wat to do this other than a loop. The best I came up was array.forEach().

Comment: @Odin there may be any number of arguments.

Comment: Shame you aren't using C++, you can do this very easily with variadic templates :)

Comment: Shame you aren't using Scala, you could do this very easily in one single short line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is, you could even use the reduce function:

```
function sum() { 
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
          .reduce(function(p,c) {return p+c}); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Array.prototype.reduce can be used on the arguments

```
function add() {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    arguments,
    function(a, b) { return a + b });
}
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, 1 less function call (:

Answer (score 0):

I rather say this is a [codegolf.stackexchange.com](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) question. But yes, there is a way, you could use recursion:

```
function add() {
    // just in case someone will try to run the function without arguments
    if (!arguments.length) {
        throw new Error("add(): Function call with no arguments.");
    } 

    // final return
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return arguments[0];
    }

    // removing first element from array and saving it in variable 'number'
    // we use Array.prototype.shift.apply() because 'arguments' is an array-like
    // object, and doesn't have shift() method
    var number = Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);

    // this is a bit hacky, adding number to the first element of 'arguments'
    arguments[0] += number;

    // recursively calling function with new arguments
    return add.apply(this, arguments);
}

add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```